# Avifile32, can't open file with AviManager

Tags: c#, avi

I am facing an issue with the AviManager library. I want to create an AVI file to store a video, but I keep getting an error on this line:

```
_aviManager = new AviManager(@"c:\\Recordings\\test.avi", false);
```

Looking into the library, this method looks like this:

```
public AviManager(String fileName, bool open){
        Avi.AVIFileInit();
        int result;
        if(open){ //open existing file

            result = Avi.AVIFileOpen(
                ref aviFile, fileName,
                Avi.OF_READWRITE, 0);
        }else{ //create empty file

            result = Avi.AVIFileOpen(
                ref aviFile, fileName,
                Avi.OF_WRITE | Avi.OF_CREATE, 0);

        }
        if(result != 0) {
            throw new Exception("Exception in AVIFileOpen: "+result.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Because the file currently does not exist, it should enter the else part and create a new file. It creates the file but then it crashes because the result took the value `-2147205009`. My question is, why does it do this?

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Exception in AVIFileOpen: -2147205009

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this was caused in my case by a stream not being properly disposed (so once opened the "*.avi" file became locked and then every next opening attempt ended up with this error).

To avoid that please ensure that you close/dispose all the AVI objects in the correct order:
CORRECT:

```
aviManager.Close();
newStream.GetFrameClose();
```

and also remove all the "nulling" like aviManager=null; etc. from the end of code (it caused some random issues on my machine).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is in the path. Is the folder `C:\Recordings` created before creating the `test.avi` file? Try to create the path in the system first:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Where

```
path = @"c:\Recordings"
```

(Using "\\" together with "@" is unnecessary, because backslash is escaped in either way.)